# Android Studio set up wizard problems

Tags: android

Android Studio forces me to "uninstall previous version" and installs a new version every time I try to open it.  I have tried to completely uninstall android studio and i have re downloaded it.  The software just makes no sense.  If I close my project it takes forever to get back into android studio.  Importing projects is a pain in the ass as well.  I have tried to follow along the Lynda simple note taking app and it will not allow me to import the material design project.  I know its a little off topic but if anyone can help with either of these issues i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't quite clear enough to answer. Maybe make 1 question per issue, and include a screenshot of the error messages?

Comment: Did you check your system for the minimum requirements? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html Also, there is a guide for installing the SDK and getting started: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio